# datadog metrics: how to sum after avg?

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

We have metric called 'crawl':

The tags are:

- 1, `stages`, values are stage1, stage2, and stage3,
- 2, `sources`, values are A, B, C
- 3, other tags, like `cluster_name`, etc

i need to total time spent on stage1, stage2, stage3 for each sources.

i hope to sum the following metrics by `stages` (stage1+stage2+stage3):

`avg:crawl.histogram.95percentile{cluster_name:X} by {stages,sources}`

How can i do it? Thanks

Comment: I do not want to do following: (define three several series and then sum them)

```
a  = avg:crawl.histogram.95percentile{cluster_name:X, stages: stage1} by {sources}
b  = avg:crawl.histogram.95percentile{cluster_name:X, stages: stage2} by {sources}
c  = avg:crawl.histogram.95percentile{cluster_name:X, stages: stage3} by {sources}

a+b+c
```